# LaTeX3 error "Backend request inconsistent" when using xelatex + dvisvgm

Tags: xetex, dvisvgm

The following example aims to produce an svg output, using tikz library `animations`.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass[tikz, dvisvgm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{animations}
\begin{document}
\tikz \node
  :fill opacity = {0s="0", 5s="1"}
  :rotate = {6s="0", 10s="360", repeats, restart=false}
  [fill=blue!20, draw=blue, ultra thick, circle] {Hello!};
\end{document}
```

In the `tex -> dvi/xdv` process, `xelatex -no-pdf main` produces latex3 error

```
! LaTeX3 Error: Backend request inconsistent with engine: using 'xdvipdfmx'
(LaTeX3)        backend.
```

But both `pdflatex -output-format=dvi main` and `lualatex -output-format=dvi main` work fine. I am using

- LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
- L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>

This might be related to LaTeX2e release 2020-02-02, since in this release `expl3` is packaged into latex format.

#### Question

Why the example works for both pdflatex and lualatex, but not xelatex? Is this a problem?

#### Workaround

Clear the latex3 inner macro storing backend name before `\documentclass` fixes the problem.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_clear:N \c_sys_backend_str
\ExplSyntaxOff
\documentclass[tikz, dvisvgm]{standalone}
... ...
```

Comment: Can dvisvgm handle a xdv from xelatex?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes. dvisvgm recognizes xdv as dvi version 5 to 7. With the workaround, dvisvgm produces valid svg from xdv.

Comment: Then we should allow for this. Add an issue to the latex3 tracker at GitHub.

Comment: What do you gain by using xelatex compared to dvilualatex?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Added here https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/677. Currently and personally, no expected gain. I use xelatex by default since I need the xetex-only package xeCJK to handle Chinese. So I encounter the reported problem incidentally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been reported to and fixed by latex3 [1]. The fix is contained in l3kernel 2020-02-21 [2].

---

[1] https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/677

[2] https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/2020-02-21/l3kernel/CHANGELOG.md#2020-02-21